# coc.nvim: Open function or class definition in a new terminal tab

Tags: neovim, coc.nvim

Most of the time I use the `gd` command then I have to browse the file manually in a new terminal tab, because I still need to leave open the previous file.

It would be just a bit useful to be able to open the definition in a new tab, of course, I'm just wondering if this is possible and how to configure it, probably mapping a new command in the nvim config file?

This is how I'm mapping the `gd` command:

```
nmap <silent> gd <Plug>(coc-definition)
```

Comment: Thank you however not sure how to translate the command to what I need, I just updated my answer so you understand how I have it mapped

Comment: well it opens another "kind of" tab, but it's not a tab, however, it just stays on the file, does not go to the definition

Comment: What I meant is that it's not the regular terminal tab that opens when I press `cmd+t`

Comment: Oh I see - I thought you meant vim tabs. I'll remove these my comments so as not to clutter you post. Good luck with finding a solution!

Comment: Ho wel I think you were close as well, if I can manage to do what I need using vim tabs that would work as well!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You shouldn't open in new terminal tab, because this means you'll start a new vim process instance and will launch a new language server process that you use. If you're using some other vim remote plugins, they'll be loaded again.

You can set `"coc.preferences.jumpCommand": "tabe"` in your coc-settings.json, this will open in vim tabs.

Comment: well at least a workaround that I think will be useful, thank you